# Lucene IndexSearcher thread safe

Tags: lucene

As per

> http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/LuceneFAQ#Is_the_IndexSearcher_thread-safe.3F

the IndexSearcher is thread safe.
However, I think this refers to the latest implementation of Lucene.
I'm using Lucene 3.0.3 and I`m interested in knowing if in this version the IndexSercher is thread safe, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is thread-safe. Just look at the corresponding [Javadoc API](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html):

> **`IndexSearcher` instances are completely thread safe**, meaning multiple
>   threads can call any of its methods, concurrently. If your application
>   requires external synchronization, you should not synchronize on the
>   IndexSearcher instance; use your own (non-Lucene) objects instead.